# Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'nimoConfigurationBean' is defined

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, frameworks, rad

I am using Spring in my Jar file to get the properties from a properties file. I am getting output when i try from my RAD(eclipse). but when i deploy my jar file in server, i keep getting this error.

```
ERROR:

Exception 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'nimoConfigurationBean' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1044)
```

The error occurs when i get bean:

```
**NimoConfigurationBean obj = (NimoConfigurationBean) context.getBean("nimoConfigurationBean");**
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://xml.westfieldgrp.com/public/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://xml.westfieldgrp.com/public/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://xml.westfieldgrp.com/public/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd" >    
    <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/config/devint/nimo.properties"/>
    </bean>  
    <bean id="nimoConfigurationBean" scope="singleton"
        class="com.westfieldgrp.filenet.env.NimoConfigurationBean">
        <property name="serviceUser" value="${env.user}" />
        <property name="servicePass" value="${env.pass}" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Call in Java: 
    public class AddEnvProperty {

```
             public String envType(String propertyValue) {  
        String returnValue = "";

        AddEnvProperty envProps = new AddEnvProperty();
        NimoConfigurationBean nimoConfigurationBean = envProps.getConfig();

        PluginLogger logger = new PluginLogger(new ResponceFilterPlugin());
        logger.logDebug(this, "envType", "Getting Property Value" + propertyValue);
        try {

             if (propertyValue == "USER") {
                returnValue = nimoConfigurationBean.getServiceUser();
            } else if (propertyValue == "PASS") {
                returnValue = nimoConfigurationBean.getServicePass();
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.logError(this, "envType", "NullPointerException:", ex);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.logError(this, "envType", "NullPointerException:", ex);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private NimoConfigurationBean getConfig() {
       ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/com/xml/*applicationContext.xml");

        NimoConfigurationBean obj = (NimoConfigurationBean) context.getBean("nimoConfigurationBean");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Getter, setter methods in NimoConfigurationBean.java

Comment: Are you sure your config file is in your classpath?

Answer (score -1):

NoSuchBeanDefinitionException is thrown by Spring container, if the bean configurable sources is not available at load time. In your case the configurable source is XML, i.e. your application context xml is not available to spring. make sure that your XML is packaged and available to class path.

Comment: Before i used to get XML not found but after adding class path like "classpath*:/com/xml/*applicationContext.xml" that error is gone and now i am getting bean error.